# What type of electrical wire inside an attached shed?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

I’m wondering for the sake of code, if a “sort of attached” shed requires NMWU (suitable for wet)?

I have an outlet on my exterior wall (regular 14/2). I have the wall opened and want to rerun the wire through the sealed carport ceiling and into an attached shed, with an exterior outlet.

From reading I gather within the shed the wire needs to be protected (conduit, armored, etc) as it would be exposed (not behind drywall).

Does it need to be wet rated as well?

Or because the shed is attached via attached carport with the sealed ceiling, does it follow the same rules I would in the house?

Location : Canada

Comment: Don't know the code enough, but an open type carport and a  “sort of attached” shed would probably be close enough to qualified as a wet/damp location.  Exterior outlets need to be GFCI protected, but it is recommended to have the GFCI inside of the house, breaker or another outlet on same circuit.